# Compile error in cc

Tags: c, cc, minix

At the very beggining of my main method I have

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]){
if(argc!=2){
   printf("not enough arguments");
   exit(-1);
}
/* rest of code */
}
```

But compiling with cc prints

```
line 11 } missing before int
line 12 argv undefined
line 14 for deleted
line 21 identifier missing before type_identifier
line 26 ; missing before {
```

If i remove that if, errors are gone.

Comment: You have an `=` where there should be `)` after `argv[]`

Comment: wops, miss clicked, after argv[] there is ), not =

Comment: So you've fixed the problem now?

Comment: No, problem is still there, i just failed at writting it here...

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
if(argc!=2){
   printf("not enough arguments");
   exit(-1);
}
/* rest of code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing ) for the main function args
main(int argc, char *argv[])
...